# Is it normal to over flow little battery liquid

Tags: battery, car, alternator, charging, alto

I got an overflow issue with my car's old battery and now replaced it with a new one.
currently, when I go for a long drive few vapors are released through the overflow exit side of the battery. Is it normal to happen like this?

```
Am using a Maruthi Suzuki alto car with an Exide battery
```

When I reached the service station they checked the output from the alternator and battery point, They tell me there is no sign of overcharging & everything seems ok.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of "sweating" is unavoidable and considered normal. Larger fluid escape is not ok. A photo might be helpful.

It is further advisable to use one of the older "maintainable" batteries, over those "maintenance-free" (read non-maintainable), and regularly top up with distilled water.